# cURL error 60: Peer’s Certificate issuer is not recognized

Tags: ssl, centos6, curl, virtualmin

I have a store build in wordpres which offers wordpress templates and it has an updater system.

My server is centos 6.9 and Im using virtualmin.
Comodo SSL and php7 but the people when try to update their themes they get the messagge `Download faild.cURL error 60: Peer’s Certificate issuer is not recognized.`

Sorry Im not an expert with servers but Im very confused with this issue if any one know a solution any help would be very appreciated.Thankyou.

Also after moving my domain to ssl I see that Im going down in google ranking to, maybe because of this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have problem with root and intermediate certificate. If you add only one SSL Certificate, there could be some SSL errors. You could check your site by [SSL Cheker](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and if problem exist, fix it by adding required certificates.

Comment: Alexander thanks for you reply, in fact Im using virtualmin with a shared ip for all my virtual servers.So, Im not a server expert as I told above and Im using virtualmin because its easy for me in the link that you sent me I got this window. https://s14.postimg.org/8kpiimmr5/Schermata_2017-05-09_alle_22.05.40.png Im worried because I was on the top in google and my links are going away one by one :(

Comment: here is the resul Im making it public goo.gl/kjOS3y

Comment: @Gazi, as you can see, there is chain issue. I grab your certificate from site and add required certificates from Comodo, Please check https://pastebin.com/kgdVtqUF

Comment: Alexander Im not familiar with this job please if you have time can you explain it what should I do exactly?

Comment: should I do something like this one in my virtualmin panel? https://www.virtualmin.com/node/35815 realy Im not sure what to do I lost my traffic because of that

Comment: @Gazi you should do mentioned in your link. You can take certificate chain from my pastebin, put it to one file and upload it as certificate. Or you can take certificate chain from SSLChecker.

Comment: omg my friend now in the online tool that you sent me I got the A because I download the ssl .ca file from mail mailbox and updated in virtualmin I think its fine now goo.gl/sMttVo :( I used in this way for months I was on the top and now I lost my serp

Comment: please can you confirm if its fine now?

Comment: Yes, now everything is ok. You can mark my answer as right.

Comment: you saved my life Alexander I think this was the problem why I was going down in google rank :( thankyou so much